# Pandas excel reading buffer error (python 3)

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a problem reading an excel file from a download link using pandas. The excelString below loads correctly and looks like an excel file, but when trying to convert it to excel using pandas it says the file name is too long. Any assistance would be appreciated. This is a useful generic problem to solve for anyone accessing iShares index membership info.

```
import urllib
import pandas as pd
f = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.ishares.com/us/239714/fund-download.dl')
excelString = f.read().decode('utf-8')
pd.ExcelFile(excelString)
```

The Error returned is OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me using Python3 and pandas 0.16.2 - do you have the latest version?